# How to realize the idea? use Controller, ServiceImple, Repository, Presentation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

how to realize the idea?
Send me information: {"idBanner":2, "fullnameClient":"Aria"}.
If click don't contain in database, then click save and send email businesscenter. Else, send a message: "you responsed".

(Entity) : Click bind Banner, Banner bind Businesscentr

Method post, body : {"idBanner":2, "fullnameClient":"Aria"}

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: which query? what is the exception?

Comment: @Query(value = "insert into Click (fullnameClient, idBanner) VALUES (:fullnameClient, :idBanner)", nativeQuery = true)
String sentsaveclick(@Param("fullnameClient") String fullnameClient, @Param("idBanner") long idBanner);

Comment: Why are you trying to work around JPA and Spring Data JPA? JPA manages all that for you but you are trying to work around that. Let JPA do its thing instead of trying to be smarter then your JPA mapping framework (else don't use JPA but simply use plain JDBC).

Comment: you never invoke this method from service class. Also native insert shouldn't return `String`. What result are you expecting for?

Comment: yes my error, string change void

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to mix two approaches: using JPA and JDBC. In general you should avoid of using native queries in JPA, JPA entities have own life cycle, and managed by EntityManager.

Your code for service could looks like:

```
     @Transactional
     public Click sentSaveClick(String fullnameClient, long idBanner) {
        Banner banner = bannerRepositor.findOne(idBanner); //get existing banner from DB
        Click click = new Click(); //create new detached instance of Click class
        click.setBanner(banner); //set banner
        click.setFullnameClient(fullnameClient); //set fullName
        click = clickRepository.save(click); //store it to DB and get managed instance of Click
        return click;
    }
```

Also be careful with types which are you returning in your queries. For example, `sent` returns `String` but type for `idClick` is `long`.

you can replace this query with JPA version:

```
    @Query("FROM Click WHERE fullnameClient = :fullnameClient AND banner.idBanner = :idBanner")
    Click sent(@Param("fullnameClient") String fullnameClient, @Param("idBanner") long idBanner);
```

and for service:

```
 @Transactional
 public boolean sent(String fullnameClient, long idBanner) {
    Click click = clickRepository.sent(fullnameClient, idBanner); 
    return click != null;
}
```

Comment: mix two approaches: using JPA and JDBC - this because use @Query ?

Comment: because you trying to store data into DB directly using `nativeQuery`, outside of JPA.

Comment: Update answer. but get HTTP Status 415. {"idBanner":2, "fullnameClient":"sanya"}. Expected return responseonclick = "you have responded", as there is a record in the database.

Comment: Because in annotation `@RequestMapping` you have `produced="application/json"` but `you have responded` is obviously not json

Comment: tell me how to change.                                                               @Transactional
    public  .... sentemail(long idBanner) {

        Banner banner = bannerRepository.findOne(idBanner); //get existing banner from DB
        banner.getBusinesscentr().getEmail();//get email Bc

        return banner.getBusinesscentr().getEmail();//get email Bc;
      
    }

Comment: return Businesscentr ?

Comment: I must pull email from Presentation ? add presentation  BusinnescentrPresentation ?

Comment: @NewWave it really depends, what kind of information user is waiting for from `POST /sentemail`. If he is waiting for all information about BusinessCentre, then I would recommended to create new `BusinnescentrPresentation` and return it. If, like it was before, user waiting for just email, send him simple json `{"email": "ema@il.com"}`. In other words, keep your external  contracts as simple as it possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134417/discussion-between-vlad-bochenin-and-new-wave).

Comment: Project nowhere red highlightsh. But stars has error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944580/tune-method-in-controller-responsebody?noredirect=1#comment71071360_41944580