# Tune method in Controller. [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-entitymanager

how to realize the idea?
Send me information: {"idBanner":2, "fullnameClient":"Aria"}.
If click don't contain in database, then click save and send email businesscenter. Else, send a message: "you responsed".
Error maybe version dependences? 
(Entity) : Click bind Banner, Banner bind Businesscentr.

Comment: Can you also add your DatabaseConfig.java ?

Comment: yes, sure, but i think error ServiceImpl

Comment: Also provide entire stacktrace , so that we can detect the actual cause of BeanCreationException..

Comment: What annotations do you have on DatabaseConfig class ?

Comment: Configuration
EnableJpaRepositories("com.qoobico.remindme.server.repository")
EnableTransactionManagement
PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
ComponentScan("com.qoobico.remindme.server")

Comment: What properties do you have in hibernate.properties?

Comment: hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect
hibernate.show_sql = true

hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate

Comment: In the ClickServiceImpl  are you wiring the bannerRepository and businesscentrRepository?

Comment: It could be a problem like a NullPointer inside one of those repositories.

Comment: I did not understand about wiring. Probably, did not do it

Comment: private ClickRepository clickRepository - work good.
private BannerRepository bannerRepository; private BusinesscentrRepository businestsentrRepository - displayed :never assigned

Comment: Add Autowired (like in private ClickRepository clickRepository;) on the bannerRepository and businesscentrRepository and try again.

Comment: How connect other Repository(BusinesscentrRepository,BannerRepository) in ClickServicImpl

Comment: Thank, this connected Repo, but same problem exists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134418/discussion-between-new-wave-and-reos).

Comment: @reos,@Vipol Panth. version dbcp 2.1 in  pom.xml , maybe version dependence

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134425/discussion-between-new-wave-and-reos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [id_bc] in table [banner]; found [int (Types#INTEGER)], but expecting [bigint (Types#BIGINT)]**

This is the problem which is causing this

Stack trace it is mention that hibernate is validating your schema where it is finding wrong column type, this happen when **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate** ,

Now you can keep this property hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update , so that it will update the changes made in your entities,

or just change your database schema and make the type of this column as big integer, as in your entities you are using long.

Also, no need to recreate database when you are using **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update** hibernate won't validate your schema in this case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remade database, changed in `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create`